# Why is this still 'unclear'?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I recently asked a question that was subsequently put 'on hold' for being 'unclear'. I then edited it pretty drastically, and as far as I can tell there is nothing really unclear about the new version, but it was still not re-opened. The question can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195069/a-relation-that-commutes-with-logical-equivalence

My question for this forum is now the following: What part of my question is still unclear?

Comment: Since you edited the question after it was closed, it automatically entered the reopen review queue. The fact that it hasn't been reopened indicates that people still consider it unclear; it's not a matter of being forgotten. It is a good idea to ask for clarification here. (This is just a technical remark. It's beyond my expertise to comment on the question itself.)

Comment: Oh dear. Well, what to do then? Is the whole question just gone? 
But if I click on the link in the current post, I can still see it.

Comment: I see. So I can only wait and hope, apparently. Which brings me back to the above question.

Comment: OK, thanks! ______________

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the question on MO main it asks about has been deleted in the meantime.

Comment: I find it pretty disappointing (sickening, actually) that questions can simply get deleted without anyone giving any reasons for that. It's not like my question was facetious or anything.

Comment: @user270264: Your question was probably just autodeleted, without further human intervention -- for autodeletion rules, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Comment: OK, thanks, but I can't say that I approve of that algorithm for auto-deletion. My question has been around not even for a month, and there would (I think) still have been a decent chance that someone who has some expertise in mathematical logic might stumble upon it and provide  useful feedback.